# Why is $\int f+ g d \mu \geq \int f d \mu + \int g d \mu$

Tags: probability-theory

Hi I was studying probability theory and in extending the definition of integral from bounded functions with finite support to positive values functions I got stuck . As you can see in the picture I took I don't follow why the L.H.S is greater than the R.H.S

$\int f+ g d \mu \geq \int f d \mu + \int g d \mu$

I mean usually the argument is that the sup of the sum is less than equal to the sum of the sup but it seems to be work the other way around . 
[image]

The integral is defined on the picture in step 3 .

Please forgive me for the bad typesetting . I am using my mobile as my computer is kaput . 
Thank you

Comment: It's near impossible to read the writing in the picture. Perhaps take another photo so we can see it more clearly.

Comment: Write down the part where you don't understand what happens. Posting pictures is only acceptable if there is no other way to get your question across.

Comment: @5xum I am sorry, I will be very careful next time. But my question has already been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it cannot be seen clearly, I think the steps you have problem with is this,
$$\int{(f+g)}d\mu=\inf_{\psi\leq f+g}\int\psi d\mu$$
$$\leq\inf_{\psi_1\leq f, \psi_2\leq g}\left(\int\psi_1 d\mu+\int\psi_2 d\mu\right).$$
Just note that  $\psi_1\leq f$ and $\psi_2\leq g \implies\psi=\psi_1+\psi_2\leq f+g$. Set-theoretically, we have the following inclusion,
$$\left\{\int\psi d\mu : \psi\leq f+g  \right\}\supseteq \left\{\int\left(\psi_1+\psi_2\right)d\mu : \psi_1\leq f, \psi_2\leq g\right\}.$$

Therefore, the inf of the left-hand set is smaller than the inf of the right-hand set.

On the other hand, I think up to this point, your book should have proved the linearity of the integration on those $\psi$'s (on *Kubrusly*, they are simple functions.) Therefore $$\int\left(\psi_1+\psi_2\right)d\mu=\int\psi_1 d\mu+\int\psi_2 d\mu.$$

Combining these two facts and you get the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was precisely why the set inclusion holds. But now I am convinced . Thank you so much for your time